# Port no 8080 is already in use when running Solr with runjetty

Tags: solr, jetty

When I am running solr with runjetty in eclipse ,I am getting an exception(`IlleagalStateException`) and port no:8080 already in use?

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I would recommend checking to see what is already running on port 8080. What OS are you using? If windows, open a command line and enter `netstat -a` and check for the port in question.

Comment: just a suggestion: next time you ask, don't confuse the title with the body of your question. also, provide all the informations you can, or we won't be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

in your solr installation folders, search for "example/etc/jetty.xml"

this is the relevant part you're looking for:

```
<Set name="port">
    <SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8080"/>
</Set>
```

change the "default" value as you like (unused port)

or launch jetty adding

```
-Djetty.port=11111
```

from the command line (1111 is just a random number, you choose again the one you need)

Answer (score 1):

This means that there is a java service which is using the port, go to task manager and process and kill any javaw process that is running currently ...

Hope that might fix.

Comment: How would you *possibly* know it's specifically a java service? ;)

Answer (score 0):

change you apache tomcat port to some other port and try again...

Please set port value in server.xml file
Its path is like,

```
Tomcat-installation-dir\conf\server.xml
```

Search tag like this,

```
<!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

Change the port number to any other number like 9090 for example, and after changes it should look like this,

```
<!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 9090 -->
<Connector port="9090" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

Dont change anything other than connector port,change only the value of port and save the file and now hit the url,

```
localhost:9090
```

Or use the port number which you have updated in the server.xml file.

```
localhost:port_in_server.xml
```

So if every thing goes fine it should open the tomcat home page....This will make sure that you have changed the tomcat's default port(i.e.8080)listen to 9090.
Shutdown the tomcat server at this point.
Now you stop and restart the jetty server and it will work for you with no issues..

Hope this helps....